# how to move programs in the taskbar without making them favourites?

Tags: gui, taskbar

by default, when a program in moved up [my taskbar is on the left side of the screen], it becomes favorite program and is pinned on the taskbar. but i want to just move around the programs without making them favourite, is there some way to do so?

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using. I use Ubuntu 20.04 and it does not do that.

Comment: @David i am using ubuntu 20.04. if it does not do that in your settings, is there a way that i can make it like yours?

Comment: No idea I do not mess with setting all is default. Using gnome DE

Answer (score 0):

In 20.04 (and ubuntu generally) this only occurs if you are actually running the program and is the default position.

There is no way of changing this behaviour.

If, for some unspecified reason, you wish to move the position of the icon on the dock whilst you are running the program, do so as required then after you have finished with it, right click on the icon and select `Remove from Favourites` after which it can again be selected from `Show Applications` as per normal.

Comment: Yes. Even the **Dash to Panel** extension does _not_ allow this.